# I can't download pages after javascript have executed. Final version of page.

Tags: javascript, download

I'm scraping websites, but there are few which doesn't display correctly because of javascript. So I need scraper which can also process javascript&iframes (like browser) and give me final output of the page.

I wanted to get this thing running on php, but so far it seems that it's impossible because javascript executes in client side, but php is server side process. Tried file_get_contents & curl. Also simpletest.

So I searched for solution in c#. 
Found out about selenium and just spent all day trying to figure out how to set up everything. Too bad that selenium also downloads the page before javascript executes.

I'm getting tired and desperate. 
Can anyone give me any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a headless browser.  There's one for python called Mechanize:
[here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize)

Also, there's HtmlUnit.  HtmlUnit was created in Java but can be ported to C# (rather easily with IKVM).

Here is information on how to port it to C#: [how to use HtmlUnit in C#](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/03/30/using-htmlunit-on-net-for-headless-browser-automation/)